# Dynamically update all instances of multiple input function

Tags: python

I'm creating a program with a class that has 3 input attributes.  The program calls a function that creates many of these objects with their inputs being given based on some other criteria not important to this question.

As I further develop my program, I may want to add more and more attributes to the class.  This means that I have to go and find all instances of the function I am using to create these objects, and change the input arguments.

For example, my program may have many of these:

```
 create_character(blue, pizza, running)
```

where inputs correspond to character's favorite color, food, and activity.  Later, I may want to add a fourth input, such as favorite movie, or possibly a fifth or sixth or ninety-ninth input.

Do professional programmers have any advice for structuring their code so that they don't have to go through and individually change each line that the create_character function is called so that it now has the new, correct number of inputs?

Find and replace seems fine, but this makes error possible, and also seems tedious.  I'm anticipating calling this function at least 50 times.

Comment: Welp, find all + replace all is a start...

Comment: My question literally asks if there is an alternative to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of a few options for how you could design your class to make easier to extend later new kinds of "favorite" things.

The first approach is to make most (or all) of the arguments optional. That is, you should specify a default value for each one (which might be `None` if there's not a real value that could apply as a default). This way, when you add an extra argument, the existing places that call the function without the new argument will still work, they'll just get the default value.

Another option would be to use a container (like a dictionary) to hold the values, rather than using a separate variable or argument for each one. For instance, in your example could represent the character's favorites using a dictionary like `favorites = {'color': blue, 'food': pizza, 'activity': running}` (assuming the those values are defined somewhere), and then you could pass the dictionary around instead of the separate items. If you use the `get` method of the dictionary, you can also make this type of design use default values (`favorites.get('movie')` will return `None` if you haven't updated the code that creates the dictionary to add a `'movie'` key yet).

Comment: I like both of these ideas, and I might end up using some variation of your dictionary approach.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of [argument/keyword argument unpacking](https://hangar.runway7.net/python/packing-unpacking-arguments) to support dynamically-changing function parameters. And also factory function/classes that generate the function you need:

```
def create_character(required1, required2, *opt_args, **kwargs):
    """ create_character must always be called with required1 and required2
    but can receive *opt_args sequence that stores arbitrary number of
    positional args. kwargs hold a dict of optional keyword args """

    for i, pos_arg in enumerate(opt_args):
        # pos_arg walks opt_args sequence
        print "position: {}, value: {}".format(i+3, pos_arg)

    for keyword, value in kwargs:
        print "Keyword was: {}, Value was: {}".format(keyword, value)
```

---

```
pos_args = (1,2,3)
create_character('this is required','this is also required', *pos_args)
""" position: 3, value: 1
    position: 4, value: 2
    position: 5, value: 3 """
```

---

```
a_dict = {
    'custom_arg1': 'custom_value1',
    'custom_arg2': 'custom_value2',
    'custom_arg3': 'custom_value3'
}   

create_character('this is required','this is also required', **a_dict)
""" Keyword was: custom_arg2, value: custom_value2
    Keyword was: custom_arg3, value: custom_value3
    Keyword was: custom_arg1, value: custom_value1 """
```

Comment: This looks super neat!  I'm pretty sure this is exactly what I'm looking for, but I'll have to play around with it a little.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I really like the list or dictionary input method, but it was still messy and allowed for the possibility of error. What I ended up doing was this:

I changed the class object to have no inputs.  Favorites were first assigned with random, default, or unspecified options.

After the class object was created, I then edited the attributes of the object, as so:

```
self.favorite_movie    = "unspecified"
self.favorite_activity = "unspecified"

new_character = (character())
new_character.favorite_movie = "Dr. Strangelove"
```

I think that the downside to this approach is that it should be slower than inputting the variables directly.  The upside is that this is easy to change in the future.  Perhaps when the program is finished, it will make more sense to then convert to @Blckknight 's method, and give the input as a list or dictionary.